# Firefox ctrl+1, ctrl+n to open tab from speed dial

Tags: firefox, opera

I'm trying to migrate from Opera to Firefox, and I've found several add-ons to make it happen, but there is still one thing missing. Opera had the speed dial, so anywhere I was, if I hit Ctrl+1, it opened Gmail (for me), and Ctrl+2, it opened Facebook, etc, in order how they were on my homepage. Anyone has an idea to make it happen? Thanks!

Comment: I'd need the hotkey functionality, not the home page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Firefox uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>8</kbd> to select tab 1-8, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to select the last tab.

You can override the default behavior by using the [Speed Dial](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/speed-dial/) add-on by Josep del Rio; just make sure to enable the **Load in blank new tabs** option. Check the official [manual](http://speeddial.uworks.net/manual.html) for further information and customization options.

*Tested with Firefox 27.0.1.*

## References

- [Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly)
- [How to use hotkeys to open speed dial websites in Firefox and Chrome [Guide]](http://dottech.org/143325/how-to-use-hotkeys-to-open-speed-dial-websites-in-firefox-and-chrome-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm not familiar with speeddial in opera, but if it is like the speeddial I know for firefox this might do the trick: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fvd-speed-dial/ (not to sure about the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + {1,2,..} function)

Also you can add a keyword to a bookmark (say fb for facebook). Type this keyword in your addressbar and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and firefox will open de link you connected.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: the important thing would be the hotkey, not the speed dial. Tried fvd-speed-dial, it didn't have the hotkeys. keyword bookmarks are still a long overhead.. but thanks for your answer!